# Private pypi server on localhost

Tags: python, pip, pypi

How can I use **pip** for installing and uploading packages to my **localhost** just to test how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for setting up a local, private equivalent of the PyPI server. Some of the most well-known:

- https://devpi.net/
- https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/